# Javascript: switch doesn't match the variable value pulled from cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, switch-statement, case

This script should count how many times the cookie is set and do something specific when the count is 1 or 2. For some reason it won't match the 1 in the switch. I have tried doing it as a string "1" and I have tried rewriting it many different ways. Nothing seems to get it to match.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">


function SetCookie(name, value, time)
{
    var expires = new Date();    expires.setTime( expires.getTime() + time );    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + expires.toGMTString() + '; path=/';
}

function GetCookie(name)
{

    var cookies = document.cookie.toString().split('; ');
    var cookie, c_name, c_value;

    for (var n=0; n<cookies.length; n++)
    {
        cookie  = cookies[n].split('='); c_name  = cookie[0]; c_value = cookie[1];

        if ( c_name == name )
        { return c_value; }
    }
    return null;
}

function CheckTarget(e)
{
    var cookieValue = GetCookie('vrOp');    

    if (cookieValue === null) {
                var cookieOp = 1;
                SetCookie('vrOp',  cookieOp, 5*24*60*60*1000);
    }
    else {

    switch(cookieValue)
        {           
            case 1:
                var cookieOp = cookieValue + 1;
                alert(cookieOp);
                SetCookie('vrOp', cookieOp, 5*24*60*60*1000);
                break;
            case 2:
                var cookieOp = cookieValue + 1;

                SetCookie('vrOp', cookieOp, 5*24*60*60*1000);
                break;
        }

    }
}


function InitVr()
{
    if ( document.attachEvent )
    {
        document.attachEvent( 'onclick', CheckTarget );
    }
    else if ( document.addEventListener )
    {
        document.addEventListener( 'click', CheckTarget, false );
    }
}

InitVr();

        </SCRIPT>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

If it did work you should get no reaction from the script on the first click as cookieValue is === null, except that it sets a cookie value of 1. On the second click it should alert you that the cookie value is now going to be a 2. A third click would give no alert again, but the value when then get set to 3. It is as if the switch isn't even being run.

Comment: alert or console.log the cookie value

Comment: Just an observation--except for the `alert` statement, your `case 1` and `case 2` bodies are identical.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, and using lots and lots of alerts, found out that `cookieValue` is indeed a string. My guess as to why it didn't seem to work when you changed the switch to look for strings is because it had already been set to a value that your switch was not looking for.

So, as your code stands, the order of events is as follows:

The cookie is null upon the first click (assuming a fresh environment). It is then set to the string "1"

Upon the second click, the switch statement is entered, but no values match so nothing happens

All clicks after this do the same thing as above

Now, if you change the switch to check for strings instead, inside the first case, where you expect `cookieOp` to be set with the value of 2, it is instead concatenating the 1 to its value, thus being set to the value "11".

To fix this is actually quite simple. You just need to ensure that the variable you are dealing with is a number, not a string.

```
if (cookieValue === null) {
    var cookieOp = 1;
    SetCookie('vrOp',  cookieOp, 5*24*60*60*1000);
} else {
    cookieValue = parseInt(cookieValue, 10);
    switch(cookieValue)
    {           
        case 1:
            var cookieOp = cookieValue + 1;
            ...
```

To be sure that this is working, you may want to remove the cookie that has already been set by previous testing, or put a `default` case into your switch.

Comment: Thank you so much. What I don't understand is that I KNOW I also tried case "1" to see if it was being passed as a string and it didn't work. Gremlins! But again, thanks for the simple solution. My all nighter is officially over. I can go to bed!

Comment: @user50512 I'm not sure about that either. I just tried it with `cookieValue === "1"` and it successfully entered the first case and set it to "11". Perhaps it did this before you had the alert in there, and then wasn't getting into the switch anymore? But I'm glad I could help anyway. Goodnight! haha